# Issue restarting after changing /etc/network/interfaces to a static IP Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS

Tags: networking, grub2, restart, ip, static-ip

I've been trying to set up a static IP address on my new Ubuntu build (12.04.3 LTS).

I changed the following lines in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file from:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

to:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
gateway XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
netmask XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

where the X's are my assigned static IP address, gateway, and netmask.  This works fine, and I'm able to connect to the internet.  HOWEVER, when I restart, the purple screen comes up for a second, disappears, and then a black screen with flashing white underscore comes up.  To resolve this, I've had to modify the GRUB bootloader settings to `nomodeset` when restarting so that I can get to the desktop.

If it helps, I'm booting off a solid-state drive.

Does anyone know how I can set up a static IP address without compromising my computer's boot-up sequence, or even better, does anyone know why this is occuring?

Please let me know if I can provide any additional information!  I'm relatively new to all this and help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Have you turned off network-manager?  It tends to conflict with any manual setup in interfaces, even to the point of just rewriting it.

Comment: If simply adding the `nomodeset` boot option fixes the problem, the problem isn't related to your network/interfaces file.